# How to set lightbox as div background-image?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I'm using [Lokesh Dhakar's lightbox](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options). And as we know it works like that:

```
<a href="image.png">Click to open image</a>
```

I know we can set `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to the modal image. But it only sets `<img>` element's sizes. I want to show to the user a square image even if image is not square, but **not streched**. I want to fill all place even if it crops somewhere of image.

We can do this on `<div>` and set style with `background-size:cover;` and set a `background-image`. but I can't use it in lightbox.

Is there anyone to know how can we achieve this on lightbox?

Comment: try to add in css `.lb-image{object-fit: cover; -o-object-fit: cover}`

Comment: Unfortunately not working